# Search Functionality Implemented in a transparent UITableView but it is not working. Any help is appreciated

Tags: swift, swift4, swift5

` Here is the code I implemented Search functionality with code. Didn't use storyboard.
I ran the program and saw search bar.
I tried searching elements but nothing showing up.
I debug the code as "PO Searching" -> I got the response as "False"
So I understood Search functionality code is not getting executed in the "Cell for row at Index path"
I tried my best debugging the code.
I could not able to find the mistake in the code.
How can I solve this problem? where am I missing. Any help is appreciated..

Here is the code I implemented Search functionality with code. Didn't use storyboard.
I ran the program and saw search bar.
I tried searching elements but nothing showing up.
I debug the code as "PO Searching" -> I got the response as "False"
So I understood Search functionality code is not getting executed in the "Cell for row at Index path"
I tried my best debugging the code.
I could not able to find the mistake in the code.
How can I solve this problem? where am I missing. Any help is appreciated..  `

```
import UIKit

class Cell : UITableViewCell {
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate{
  
    @IBOutlet weak var selectFruit: UIButton! 
    
    let transparentView = UIView()
    let tableView = UITableView()
    var button = UIButton()
    
    var data = [String]()
    
    var searchFruit = [String]()
    var searching : Bool = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

// Register the Cell

        tableView.register(Cell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
      
// Adding the transparent View to show array elements
  
    func addTransparentView(frame : CGRect) {
        transparentView.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(transparentView)
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y + frame.height, width: frame.width, height: 0)
        
// Implementing Search bar functionality 

        var searchBar : UISearchBar = UISearchBar()
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: tableView.frame.width-20, height: tableView.frame.height-20))
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBar.Style.prominent
        searchBar.placeholder = " Search..."
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.isTranslucent = false
        searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        searchBar.delegate = self
               
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.addSubview(searchBar)
        tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        transparentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.9)
        tableView.reloadData()
        
        let tapgesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(deleteTransparentView))
        transparentView.addGestureRecognizer(tapgesture)
        transparentView.alpha = 0
        
// Animating the transparent view 

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.transparentView.alpha = 0.5
            self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y + frame.height + 5, width: frame.width, height: CGFloat(self.data.count * 50))
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func deleteTransparentView() {
        let frame = button.frame
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.transparentView.alpha = 0
            self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y + frame.height, width: frame.width, height: 0)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
   
// Action methods along with array elements 
    @IBAction func selectFruit(_ sender: Any) {
        data = ["Apple","Apple1","Apple2","Apple3","Apple4","Oranges","Ape","Banana","Grapes","Kiwi","Kite","JackFruit"]
        button = selectFruit
        addTransparentView(frame: selectFruit.frame)
    }
    
    // MARK:- TableView Methods
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searching {
          return searchFruit.count
        } else {
            return data.count
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        if searching {
            cell.textLabel?.text = searchFruit[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange textSearched: String) {
        searchFruit = data.filter({$0.prefix(textSearched.count) == textSearched})
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        button.setTitle(data[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
        deleteTransparentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: After searching when are you reloading the `table`?

Comment: Where are you setting searching = true?

Comment: @Rob. Could you please let me know exactly where I have to reload the table and where I have to set the value to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `searching` true and reload table.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange textSearched: String) {
    searchFruit = data.filter({$0.prefix(textSearched.count) == textSearched})
    
        searching = !searchFruit.isEmpty
        tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: Thanks Bob and Vadian. I added the suggested changes to my code. Filtering elements working great. But It is filtering with only first character only. It is not filtering with all the characters I entered.  Another issue is empty tableviewcell is appearing in between. For that I used `tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView()` But it is not deleting the empty cells in between. How to over come these issues any help please

Comment: That is a different question you have to ask, if any of these answers helped you mark them as correct and give an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `searching` accordingly in `textDidChange` and there is a more efficient way to filter the data

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange textSearched: String) {
    if textSearched.isEmpty {
        searching = false
        searchFruit.removeAll()
    } else {
        searching = true
        searchFruit = data.filter{$0.range(of: textSearched, options: [.caseInsenitive, .anchored]) != nil}
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```